# Difference between area under a curve as definite integral vs antiderivatives

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Help my comprehension getting awful.. If $f(x)$ as a quadratic function of $x^2$. Then we know that its derivative is $2x$, I'll call it $f'(x)=2x$.

A. Somehow I'm only given the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of $f(x)$ which is $2x$. Then, in order to find the original $f(x)$ function, I'll have to find the antiderivatives of $f(x)$, which is the indefinite integral of $f'(x)$
$$ \int f'(x)dx = \int 2xdx $$ $$=x^2 + c=f(x)$$

B. Say I want to find the area under the $f(x)=x²$ curve, then it'll be a definite integral of
$$ 
\int\limits_{-a}^a x^2 dx = \frac{x^3}3] \begin{array}{c}a\\-a\end{array} 
$$

My question is, from both A and B cases, then the antiderivative of $f(x)$ (to restore $f'(x)$ back to $f(x)$) is a different term from the definite integral of $f(x)$, right?

In another case,
$$ \int f(x)dx = ax^2+2bx+5c $$

does that means the original $f(x)$ function being integrated, or the differentiated $f(x)$ (i mean f'(x), because by $dx$ being present I think it means that $f(x)$ is derived in respect of $x$) being found its antiderivative?

If the originals $f(x)$ function were being integrated, then does it means that taking an antiderivative could work both as to restore $f'(x)$ back to original $f(x)$ and to "elevate" $f(x)$ into higher degree (or to find the area under a curve if some intervals were taken)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean finding the antiderivative of $f'(x)$?

$$
F'(x)=f(x)\tag{1}
$$

where $F(x)$ is the antiderivative of $f(x)$

From $(1)$ you can see that $f(x)$ is just a placeholder function and can just as well be substituted for $f'(x)$, and you can still say $F(x)$ is the anti-derivative of $f'(x)$.

Also, indefinite integrals are the just the set of possible anti-derivatives as per Eq. 2.

From $(1)$, by integrating both sides:
$$
F(x)+C=\int f(x)\ dx\tag{2}
$$

where $C$ is an arbitrary constant

Assigning the result of the indefinite integral, $F(x)+C$ to a new function $G(x)$, you can clearly see that $G'(x)=F'(x)$ because the $C$ constant is equal to 0 when derived w.r.t. $x$. This means that for every possible $C$, $G(x)$ is still an antiderivative of the original function $f(x)$ (or in your case, $f'(x)$.